# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el menu dropdown aparezca como una caja?

Tags: html, css

Hola estoy haciendo un menu *dropdown* y quiero mostrar el menu desplegabl como  una caja pero cuando uso el `"display: flex"` solo me muestra una lista larga.

Este es el ejemplo:

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 10</a>
    <a href="#">Link 21</a>
    <a href="#">Link 32</a>
    <a href="#">Link 13</a>
    <a href="#">Link 24</a>
    <a href="#">Link 35</a>
    <a href="#">Link 16</a>
    <a href="#">Link 27</a>
    <a href="#">Link 38</a>
    <a href="#">Link 19</a>
    <a href="#">Link 20</a>
    <a href="#">Link 39</a>
    <a href="#">Link 18</a>
    <a href="#">Link 27</a>
    <a href="#">Link 36</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

El menú debería mostrarse como esta imagen:
[image: Ejemplo del resultado esperado]

Estaré realmente agradecido si me pudieran indicar como puedo hacer que el menú se despliegue de esa forma.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que funcione solo quitale, la propiedad: postion:relative a la clase .dropdown y agregale width:100% a la clase.dropdowncontent, luego es necesario definir cuantas columnas quieres, en este caso el width de los link es de 30% para tener 3 columnas, prueba con este estilo.

```
<style>
        .dropbtn {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 16px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .dropdown {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            width: 100%;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 30%;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #f1f1f1
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;

        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: #3e8e41;
        }

    </style>
```

Comment: y si necesito utilizar una lista como sus ul  en vez del boton??? por ejemplo            <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Noticias</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Horarios</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Regalos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Publicidad</a></li>
                        </ul>

Comment: lo mismo en ese caso tendrias que meter los ul dentro de tres div que tengan width de 30%, y los div deverian ser con float:left